# Can't Active Add-ons in Blender 3.2.2

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, error, installation

I'm using Blender 3.2.2, my add-ons need to install Pillow in blender folder first before install it in blender, so there it's not pb with that but when i active the add-ons , i got a error message.

I don't know where's a probleme.

Pls help! thx a lot.  [image]

Comment: It seems that you have not properly installed the dependency. Perhaps you can explain how you tried to install Pillow, ideally with the script you've used. [This is an example of how you could install your dependencies.](https://github.com/robertguetzkow/blender-python-examples/tree/master/add_ons/install_dependencies)

Comment: @RobertGützkow i just uninstall and install Pillow by typing on Powershell

./python.exe -m pip uninstall Pillow 
./python.exe -m pip install Pillow 

normally it' work but idk what going on

Comment: I've resolved my problem it's cuz  i'm not set myself as the owner for PowerShell.

Btw, thx for your reply!

Comment: Blender comes with its own Python interpreter. You would have to install it there.